# python UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, sockets, utf-8, byte

Just working with some sockets and receiving the error mentioned in title. Code and detailed errors below. I have already looked at some of the other similar posts, but I haven't managed to fix my issue. Appreciate any help and if you can break things down as simply as possible, so I can better understand.

when trying print(pwd) after decode: P[] #brackets are closest thing to square I could make

when trying print(pwd) before decode:

```
b'P\x01\x00\x00'
b'\xfcH\x83\xe4\xf0\xe8\xc0\x00\x00\x00AQAPRQVH1\xd2eH\x8bR`H\x8bR\x18H\x8bR H\x8brPH\x0f\xb7JJM1\xc9H1\xc0\xac<a|\x02, A\xc1\xc9\rA\x01\xc1\xe2\xedRAQH\x8bR \x8bB<H\x01\xd0\x8b\x80\x88\x00\x00\x00H\x85\xc0tgH\x01\xd0P\x8bH\x18D\x8b@ I\x01\xd0\xe3VH\xff\xc9A\x8b4\x88H\x01\xd6M1\xc9H1\xc0\xacA\xc1\xc9\rA\x01\xc18\xe0u\xf1L\x03L$\x08E9\xd1u\xd8XD\x8b@$I\x01\xd0fA\x8b\x0cHD\x8b@\x1cI\x01\xd0A\x8b\x04\x88H\x01\xd0AXAX^YZAXAYAZH\x83\xec AR\xff\xe0XAYZH\x8b\x12\xe9W\xff\xff\xff]I\xb8cmd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00APAPH\x89\xe2WWWM1\xc0j\rYAP\xe2\xfcf\xc7D$T\x01\x01H\x8dD$\x18\xc6\x00hH\x89\xe6VPAPAPAPI\xff\xc0API\xff\xc8M\x89\xc1L\x89\xc1A\xbay\xcc?\x86\xff\xd5H1\xd2H\xff\xca\x8b\x0eA\xba\x08\x87\x1d`\xff\xd5\xbb\xf0\xb5\xa2VA\xba\xa6\x95\xbd\x9d\xff\xd5H\x83\xc4(<\x06|\n\x80\xfb\xe0u\x05\xbbG\x13roj\x00YA\x89\xda\xff\xd5'
```

errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\13472\Desktop\folder\testh\testv5\testmod3Copy3.py", line 87, in <module>
    Login()
  File "C:\Users\13472\Desktop\folder\testh\testv5\testmod3Copy3.py", line 37, in Login
    pwd = pwd.decode("utf-8").strip()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0: invalid start byte
```

code snippet:

```
passwd = "Anything"

def Login():

    global s
    while True:
            string1=("Login: ")
            string1=string1.encode("utf-8")
            s.send(string1)
            pwd = s.recv(1024)
            pwd = pwd.decode("utf-8")


            if pwd.strip() == passwd:
                    break

            else:
                    continue

    string2=("You are connected! ")
    string2=string2.encode("utf-8")
    s.send(string2)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
Login()
```

Comment: It would be interesting to `print(pwd)` before the error, but it seems like the other side didn't send a utf-8 encoded clear text password.

Comment: @tdelaney just for further clarification, on the receiving end only "Login: " comes through and I don't even have a chance to put the password in before I get the error in the post. Its why I am confused on why pwd.decode is the error if I haven't even put in the password yet. To me it would make more sense if  there was an issue encoding the string "Login: "

Comment: What is the receiving end? Seems like its got a problem.

Comment: Send and receive data don't get mixed up en-route. There has to be something on the other side that sends that data. I assume `s` is a socket that has just been accepted from a `listen` command and `s.send(string1)` is the first thing sent. What about the other side that does the connection?

Comment: well I didn't feel like coding a receiving end, so I am using listeners such as netcat and metasploit in a linux terminal. Interestingly, for netcat the connection goes through with no errors but when using metasploit thats when the above error pops up.

Comment: Printing what you received may give you a hint what the problem is.

Comment: That's good to know about netcat and metasploit. I've done similar things with terminals. Depending on the terminal type, it may send control characters to the connecting device assuming its an intelligent VT terminal. metasploit, which I don't know, may well be doing the same thing.

Comment: updated a bit more of the code, and yeah I'll try printing and see what I get.

Comment: Okay so I tried printing and I updated the original post to show what I got(right before all the errors) . Not sure where the p or the square(not sure what to call it) came from as I haven't inputted anything on the receiving end yet. Note: the brackets are the closest thing I could use to make a square. Some reason it won't let me copy it onto this post.

Comment: `pwd` before decode should look like a byte string, starting with `b'\xfc` - the bytes object representation may be the best to post here.

Comment: I think the answer is that metasploit may not be the right tool for the job. There are terminal emulators for windows out there. Just find one that supports utf-8.

Comment: updated the before decode print. And yeah your probably right. Out of curiosity though can I encode/decode in something other than utf-8 to accomplish the same task?

Comment: There are many codecs in python that you can choose from. Both sides have to agree on which one to use. I tried latin1, utf-8 and utf-16-le with no luck. utf-16-be (16 bit words, big endian) and got a bunch of glyphs, chinese maybe?, but it didn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, have a good day or night!